# Synching two meshes, one with ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, shader

I've got two meshes created from the same geometry and running the same animation.  If I do absolutely nothing to the meshes they stay in perfect lockstep, which is what I want.  But if I change their position or rotation they go out of sync.

[Here's a jsfiddle of an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/oju429Ld/2/)  There's a blob of minified js at the top which contains the contents of EffectComposer.js, ShaderPass.js, RenderPass.js, MaskPass.js, and CopyShader.js from the r77 source---the three.js CDN doesn't contain them and jsfiddle won't work with linking to them from three.js github repo.  The start of the example problem is with the definition of **THREE.OutlineShader**:

```
THREE.OutlineShader = {

  uniforms: {
    "offset": {
      type: "f",
      value: 2.0
    },
    "boneTexture": {
      type: "t",
      value: null
    },
    "boneTextureWidth": {
      type: "i",
      value: null
    },
    "boneTextureHeight": {
      type: "i",
      value: null
    },
  },

  vertexShader: [
    "uniform sampler2D boneTexture;",
    "uniform int boneTextureWidth;",
    "uniform int boneTextureHeight;",
    "uniform float offset;",
    "mat4 getBoneMatrix(const in float i) {",
    "float j = i * 4.0;",
    "float x = mod(j, float(boneTextureWidth));",
    "float y = floor(j / float(boneTextureWidth));",
    "float dx = 1.0 / float(boneTextureWidth);",
    "float dy = 1.0 / float(boneTextureHeight);",
    "y = dy * (y + 0.5);",
    "vec4 v1 = texture2D(boneTexture, vec2(dx * (x + 0.5), y));",
    "vec4 v2 = texture2D(boneTexture, vec2(dx * (x + 1.5), y));",
    "vec4 v3 = texture2D(boneTexture, vec2(dx * (x + 2.5), y));",
    "vec4 v4 = texture2D(boneTexture, vec2(dx * (x + 3.5), y));",
    "mat4 bone = mat4(v1, v2, v3, v4);",
    "return bone;",
    "}",
    "void main() {",
    "mat4 boneMatX = getBoneMatrix(skinIndex.x);",
    "mat4 boneMatY = getBoneMatrix(skinIndex.y);",
    "mat4 boneMatZ = getBoneMatrix(skinIndex.z);",
    "mat4 boneMatW = getBoneMatrix(skinIndex.w);",
    "vec4 skinVertex = vec4(position + normal * offset, 1.0);",
    "vec4 skinned = boneMatX * skinVertex * skinWeight.x;",
    "skinned += boneMatY * skinVertex * skinWeight.y;",
    "skinned += boneMatZ * skinVertex * skinWeight.z;",
    "skinned += boneMatW * skinVertex * skinWeight.w;",
    "vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * skinned;",
    "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;",
    "}"
  ].join("\n"),

  fragmentShader: [
    "uniform int boneTextureWidth;",
    "void main() {",
    "gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);",
    "}"
  ].join("\n")
};

var camera, light, renderer, composer, clock;
var sceneMain, sceneOutline;
var meshMain = null,
  meshOutline = null;
var mixerMain, mixerOutline;
var animMain, animOutline;
var height = 500,
  width = 500;
var objData = '{"metadata":{"formatVersion":3.1,"generatedBy":"Blender 2.7 Exporter","vertices":24,"faces":22,"normals":18,"colors":0,"uvs":[],"materials":1,"morphTargets":0,"bones":2},"scale":1.000000,"materials":[{"DbgColor":15658734,"DbgIndex":0,"DbgName":"Material","blending":"NormalBlending","colorDiffuse":[0.1569801711586143,0.17312412519937936,0.6400000190734865],"colorEmissive":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"colorSpecular":[0.2535329759120941,0.0,0.007157782092690468],"depthTest":true,"depthWrite":true,"shading":"Lambert","specularCoef":50,"opacity":1.0,"transparent":false,"vertexColors":false}],"vertices":[1.51034,-1,-1,1.51034,-1,1,-0.489661,-1,1,-0.489661,-1,-1,1.51034,1,-1,1.51034,1,1,-0.489662,1,1,-0.489661,1,-1,3.23233,-1,-0.999999,3.23233,-1,1,3.23233,1,-0.999999,3.23233,1,1,-1.98848,-1,1,-1.98848,-1,-1,-1.98848,1,0.999999,-1.98848,1,-1,1.51034,-5.70811,-1,1.51034,-5.70811,1,3.23233,-5.70811,-0.999999,3.23233,-5.70811,1,-0.489661,-5.62708,1,-0.48966,-5.62708,-1,-1.98848,-5.62708,1,-1.98848,-5.62708,-1],"morphTargets":[],"normals":[-0.301492,-0.301492,-0.904508,-0.301492,-0.301492,0.904508,0.301492,-0.301492,0.904508,0.301492,-0.301492,-0.904508,0,0.707083,-0.707083,0,0.707083,0.707083,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.707083,0,-0.707083,0.707083,0,0.707083,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.707083,0,0.707083,-0.707083,0,-0.707083,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349],"colors":[],"uvs":[],"faces":[35,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,35,4,5,11,10,0,4,5,6,7,35,1,5,6,2,0,1,5,5,2,35,6,7,15,14,0,5,4,8,9,35,4,0,3,7,0,4,0,3,4,35,8,10,11,9,0,10,7,6,11,35,5,1,9,11,0,5,1,11,6,35,0,4,10,8,0,0,4,7,10,35,0,8,18,16,0,0,10,12,13,35,12,14,15,13,0,14,9,8,15,35,7,3,13,15,0,4,3,15,8,35,2,6,14,12,0,2,5,9,14,35,2,12,22,20,0,2,14,16,17,35,17,16,18,19,0,16,13,12,17,35,9,1,17,19,0,11,1,16,17,35,8,9,19,18,0,10,11,17,12,35,1,0,16,17,0,1,0,13,16,35,21,20,22,23,0,12,17,16,13,35,13,3,21,23,0,15,3,12,13,35,12,13,23,22,0,14,15,13,16,35,3,2,20,21,0,3,2,17,12,35,4,7,6,5,0,4,4,5,5],"bones":[{"parent":-1,"name":"leg.R","pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rotq":[-0.00523508,-0.706875,-0.707296,-0.00579363],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"parent":-1,"name":"leg.L","pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rotq":[-0.00523507,-0.706875,-0.707296,-0.00579363],"scl":[1,1,1]}],"skinIndices":[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1],"skinWeights":[0.928373,0.0680346,0.937978,0.0587701,0.949888,0.0463839,0.937937,0.0591265,0.821856,0.122838,0.79233,0.145709,0.876929,0.0825711,0.830405,0.115734,0.989868,0,0.992278,0,0.968805,0,0.966368,0,0.993762,0,0.989439,0,0.978637,0,0.962526,0.00173758,0.997334,0,0.997776,0,0.999229,0,0.999402,0,0.998345,0,0.997508,0,0.99955,0,0.999106,0],"animations":[{"name":"ArmatureAction","fps":24,"length":0.416667,"hierarchy":[{"parent":-1,"keys":[{"time":0,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[-0.00643926,-0.522937,-0.852335,-0.0044168],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.0416667,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[-0.00683821,-0.561328,-0.827555,-0.00415746],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.0833333,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[-0.00791262,-0.665775,-0.746103,-0.00335735],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.125,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[0.00910612,0.78443,0.620147,0.00222404],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.166667,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[0.00983298,0.859093,0.511724,0.00131562],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.208333,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[0.0100438,0.881367,0.472325,0.000997505],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.25,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[0.00983298,0.859093,0.511724,0.00131562],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.291667,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[0.00910612,0.78443,0.620147,0.00222404],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.333333,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[-0.00791262,-0.665775,-0.746103,-0.00335735],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.375,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[-0.00683821,-0.561328,-0.827555,-0.00415746],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.416667,"pos":[-1.24994,0.43791,0.191651],"rot":[-0.00643926,-0.522937,-0.852335,-0.0044168],"scl":[1,1,1]}]},{"parent":0,"keys":[{"time":0,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[0.0033329,0.881416,0.472275,0.00706144],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.0416667,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[0.00316317,0.858922,0.512045,0.00734349],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.0833333,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[0.00263566,0.783706,0.621074,0.00807219],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.125,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[-0.00187897,-0.664887,-0.74689,-0.00880854],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.166667,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[-0.00126496,-0.561008,-0.827759,-0.00919252],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.208333,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[-0.00104832,-0.522977,-0.852295,-0.009288],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.25,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[-0.00126496,-0.561007,-0.827759,-0.00919252],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.291667,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[-0.00187897,-0.664887,-0.74689,-0.00880854],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.333333,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[0.00263566,0.783706,0.621074,0.00807219],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.375,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[0.00316317,0.858921,0.512045,0.0073435],"scl":[1,1,1]},{"time":0.416667,"pos":[2.49995,0.280193,0.066556],"rot":[0.0033329,0.881416,0.472275,0.00706144],"scl":[1,1,1]}]}]}]}';
load();

function load() {
  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

  clock = new THREE.Clock();

  sceneMain = new THREE.Scene();
  sceneOutline = new THREE.Scene();

  var obj = loader.parse(JSON.parse(objData));
  for (var k in obj.materials) {
    obj.materials[k].skinning = true;
  }
  setModel(obj.geometry, obj.materials);
  init();
  animate();
}

function init() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, height / width, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 25);

  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff)
  light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
  sceneMain.add(light);


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    antialias: true,
  });
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  renderer.setClearColor(0x666666);
  renderer.autoClear = false;
  renderer.gammaInput = true;
  renderer.gammaOutput = true;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, {
    minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    stencilBuffer: true,
  });
  composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, renderTarget);
  composer.renderTarget1.stencilBuffer = true;
  composer.renderTarget2.stencilBuffer = true;

  var pMain = new THREE.RenderPass(sceneMain, camera);
  var pOut = new THREE.RenderPass(sceneOutline, camera);
  pOut.clear = false;
  var pCopy = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
  pCopy.renderToScreen = true;

  composer.addPass(pMain);
  composer.addPass(pOut);
  composer.addPass(pCopy);

  animMain.play();
  animOutline.play();
}

function setModel(geometry, materials) {
  meshMain = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry,
    new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
  sceneMain.add(meshMain);

  mixerMain = new THREE.AnimationMixer(meshMain);
  animMain = mixerMain.clipAction(geometry.animations[0]);

  var shader = THREE.OutlineShader;
  var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms),
    vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
    skinning: true,
    side: THREE.BackSide,
  });
  meshOutline = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, shaderMaterial);
  shaderMaterial.uniforms['boneTextureWidth'].value = meshOutline.skeleton.boneTextureWidth;
  shaderMaterial.uniforms['boneTextureHeight'].value = meshOutline.skeleton.boneTextureHeight;
  shaderMaterial.uniforms['boneTexture'].value = meshOutline.skeleton.boneTexture;
  shaderMaterial.uniforms['offset'].value = 0.5;
  shaderMaterial.uniforms['boneTextureWidth'].value.needsUpdate = true;
  shaderMaterial.uniforms['boneTextureHeight'].value.needsUpdate = true;
  shaderMaterial.uniforms['boneTexture'].value.needsUpdate = true;
  shaderMaterial.uniforms['offset'].value.needsUpdate = true;
  sceneOutline.add(meshOutline);

  mixerOutline = new THREE.AnimationMixer(meshOutline);
  animOutline = mixerOutline.clipAction(geometry.animations[0]);

}

function animate() {
  var delta = clock.getDelta();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  update(delta);
  render(delta);
}

function update(delta) {
  if (meshMain && meshOutline) {
    meshMain.rotation.y += 1 * delta;
    meshOutline.rotation.y += 1 * delta;

    mixerMain.update(delta);
    mixerOutline.update(delta);
  }
}

function render(delta) {
  composer.render(delta);
}
```

The problem is evidently due to the ShaderMaterial and/or the shader itself, as changing the second mesh's material to e.g. MeshBasicMaterial results in the expected behaviour (the two meshes staying in lockstep).

The shader was lifted from [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nv7Up/) posted some time ago.  It uses an ancient version of three.js.  I'm not entirely clear on the expected/correct way of populating the boneTexture, boneTextureWidth, and boneTextureHeight uniforms when creating the ShaderMaterial instance.  I do it manually from the values in the mesh's skeleton, but I wouldn't be surprised if that's wrong.

Again, I'm just trying to understand why translating both meshes in the same way at the same time causes them to go out of sync like illustrated in the first jsfiddle example.

**Edit**:  I observe that the mesh using ShaderMaterial (**meshOutline**) syncs with the other mesh (**meshMain**) if meshOutline is rotated exactly half as much as meshMain.  E.g., in the **update()** function:

```
meshMain.rotation.y += 1 * delta;
meshOutline.rotation.y += 1 * delta / 2;
```

...will result in the two meshes apparently rotating in sync.  The same is true if the rotation is replaced with a coordinate (e.g. x) movement:

```
//meshMain.rotation.y += 1 * delta;
//meshOutline.rotation.y += 1 * delta / 2;
var dx = Math.random() - 0.5;
meshMain.position.x += dx;
meshOutline.position.x += dx / 2;
```

...will result in both meshes moving back and forth together.  But if both
are combined, that is:

```
meshMain.rotation.y += 1 * delta;
meshOutline.rotation.y += 1 * delta / 2;
var dx = Math.random() - 0.5;
meshMain.position.x += dx;
meshOutline.position.x += dx / 2;
```

They go wildly out of sync.

**This clearly means that there's something I'm not understanding about how the shader is getting vertex positions from three.js.**  I understand that the shader is computing the vertex positions and using them because that's what happens when you use a ShaderMaterial.  What I'm not understanding is how to keep the data the shader is using current with what's happening to the mesh in three.js.  Which is apparently happening in the second jsfiddle example I linked above.

Comment: I removed everything unrelated to the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/oju429Ld/3/ A reasonable guess is the problem is in your vertex shader.

Comment: Absolutely---that was more or less my assumption from the start.  Any insight into what changed between r66 and r77 that accounts for the difference in behaviour (as discussed in my answer below)?  I ask because I believe the code in the second jsfiddle I linked (the one with the working example) was originally posted by you in answer to someone else's question some time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:  it appears as if something involving the ShaderMaterial implementation has changed since r66 (the version used in the second---working---jsfiddle example, from which I got the shader code).

What I ended up doing was going through the ShaderChunk source to see if I could reproduce what I wanted to do using chunks of shader code from the three.js source (thinking perhaps it was just some default or whatever that was getting set in the background that I wasn't doing in the custom shader code).  What I ended up with is (for the vertex shader):

```
vertexShader: [
   "uniform float offset;",
   THREE.ShaderChunk["common"],
   THREE.ShaderChunk["skinning_pars_vertex"],
   "void main() {",
      "vec3 transformed = vec3(position + normal * offset);",
      THREE.ShaderChunk["skinbase_vertex"],
      THREE.ShaderChunk["skinning_vertex"],
      THREE.ShaderChunk["project_vertex"],
   "}"
].join( "\n" ),
```

The important difference being hidden away in **skinning_vertex.glsl**, the source for the skinning_vertex shader chunk:

```
#ifdef USE_SKINNING

    vec4 skinVertex = bindMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );

    vec4 skinned = vec4( 0.0 );
    skinned += boneMatX * skinVertex * skinWeight.x;
    skinned += boneMatY * skinVertex * skinWeight.y;
    skinned += boneMatZ * skinVertex * skinWeight.z;
    skinned += boneMatW * skinVertex * skinWeight.w;
    skinned  = bindMatrixInverse * skinned;

#endif
```

The thing that's happening there that isn't in the custom shader I had (and which wasn't in the example that was working with r66) is in the first and last lines---first multiplying by **bindMatrix** and then later by **bindMatrixInverse**.  I'm a little puzzled why this is required, as [according to the docs](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/SkinnedMesh) these are two uniforms that are only defined if the SkinnedMesh has **bindMode** set to "detached" (instead of "attached", the default).

But at any rate that change---either by using the ShaderChunk-based shader or by editing my custom shader to include the differences---produces the desired result.

That answers my question, but I'd still welcome any pointers to where the documentation covers this or an explanation of the changes from r66 to r77 that explain the different behaviour.